# Create a PHP cache system in MySQL database?

Tags: php, mysql, performance, caching

I'm creating a web service that often scrapes data from remote web pages. After scraping this data, I have a simple multidimensional array of information to use. The scraping process is fairly taxing on my server, and the page load takes a while. I was considering adding a simple cache system using a MySQL database, where I create one row per remote web page with a the array of information pulled from it stored as a JSON encoded string. Is this a good enough system? Or would something like a text file per web page be a better idea?

Comment: @Kenaniah - If you have to preface with "No offense" - maybe you should just learn how to offer advice constructively. This kid is 17.

Comment: @Matt - Yeah, I'll post a constructive answer in a sec...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're scraping multiple web pages, and you want to your data to be persistently cached, you have a few options -- the best of which would be to use memcache or a database such as MySQL. Using text files is not a good idea, because you would have to serialize / deserialize your data, and read from your filesystem. To query a database or a memcache is many times more efficient.

Since you're probably looking for your cache to be somewhat persistent, I would suggest going with MySQL. You would simply create a table that has an auto-incrementing primary key, which a column for each element in your parsed JSON object. (Note that MySQL currently does not support arrays. In order to emulate them, you will need to use relational tables, or serialize your array data and provide it to a text field. The former method is preferred).

Every time you scrape a page, you would run an `UPDATE` statement to update that individual page's information in the database. If you specify a unique index on whatever you use to uniquely identify your page (URL / etc), you will achieve optimal look-up performance.

Comment: The data persistence is why I skipped over memcache or something similar. My question about querying for a cached page is: Is it ok to query simply for the page's URL, or should I do something like take an md5 hash of the url and query for that?

Comment: It's fine to query using the page's URL (as that can generally be used as a unique identifier). Just make sure you add a unique index on that field in your database table, as that would essentially function as your primary key.

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking to store the cache locally on 1 server (e.g. if your mysql server and http server are on the same box), you might be better off using [APC](http://php.net/manual/en/book.apc.php), which is a cache service that comes with PHP.

If you're looking to store the data remotely (e.g. a dedicated cache box) then I would go with [Memcache](https://www.php.net/memcache) instead of MySQL.

"When all you have is a hammer ..."

Answer (score 0):

I don;'t tend to have particularly large APC configs, 64 - 128MB max. Memcache can go to a couple of gigabytes or maybe more (far more if you run multiple instances).  Both are also transient - a restart of Apache, or Memcache (the the latter is slightly less likely, or often) will lose the data

It depends then, on how often you are willing to process the data to produce the cache, and how long that cache could otherwise be useful for. If it was good for weeks before you re-scraped the pages - Mysql is a entirely suitable backing store.

Potential pther options, depending on how many items are being cached & how big the data is, are, as you suggest, a file-based cache, SQlite, or other systems.